# How can i disable adding new item to an array in Swift?

Tags: swift

I have an array like this inside a struct:

```
struct TestType {
    
    private(set) var array: [String] = ["0", "1", "2"]
    
    mutating func updateItem0(_ value: String) {
        self.array[0] = value
    }
    
    mutating func updateItem1(_ value: String) {
        self.array[1] = value
    }
    
    mutating func updateItem2(_ value: String) {
        self.array[2] = value
    }
}
```

I want be able to disable appending method to this array when I use an instance of struct, and keeping the count of it as it is. I cannot use `private(set)` because it would not allow me to update items of it.

My idea is using `private(set)` inside struct and making a mutating function for updating items in case, I wanted to know if there is better way for it?

Answer (score 2):

Lots of options but a simple enhancement would be passing the `index`:

```
mutating func update(_ value: String, at index: Int) {
    array[index] = value
}
```

And another is to check if the operation is possible:

```
enum Error: Swift.Error {
    case indexOutOfBound
}

mutating func update(_ value: String, at index: Int) throws {
    guard array.indices.contains(index) else { throw Error.indexOutOfBound }
    array[index] = value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice way to handle it.  Add `subscript` to your `struct` which then allows you to access and change the values like you would an array.  Adopting `CustomStringConvertible` and implementing `description` allows you to print the internal array while keeping it entirely `private`:

```
struct TestType: CustomStringConvertible {
    
    private var array: [String] = ["0", "1", "2"]

    var description: String { String(describing: array) }
 
    subscript(_ index: Int) -> String {
        get {
            return array[index]
        }
        set {
            array[index] = newValue
        }
    }
}

var foo = TestType()

foo[0] = "hello"
foo[2] = "goodbye"
foo[3] = "oops" // Fatal error: Index out of range

print(foo[0]) // hello
print(foo[1]) // 1
print(foo[2]) // goodbye
print(foo)    // ["hello", "1", "goodbye"]
```